# System not executing correct pip binary

Tags: python, linux, pip

This is my PATH, with ~/.local/bin appearing before all other directories:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/tessio/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

There is a pip binary located on  ~/.local/bin/ directory:

```
$ which pip
/home/tessio/.local/bin/pip

$ /home/tessio/.local/bin/pip --version
pip 22.2.2 from /home/tessio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

But when I run pip the binary installed from the debian package runs instead:

```
$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ /usr/bin/pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

What's going on?

EDIT 1:

```
$ type -a pip
pip is /home/tessio/.local/bin/pip
pip is /usr/bin/pip
pip is /bin/pip
```

Comment: `type -a pip` ?

Comment: @phd edited the post with this information

Comment: Try rehashing maybe `hash -r` , see also `help hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running

```
hash -r
```

The problem was corrected.

hash is a bash built-in command that determines and remember the full pathname of each command name. The -r option makes it forget all previous remembered locations.

Thanks to @MarkSetchell for giving a hand.